# Validating time zone in a Joi schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, joi, moment-timezone

I want to accept a request that sends several query parameters  with it and I am validating it using Joi library in Nodejs/Express but can't figure out how to validate time zone values(which is one of the query parameters?

```
function validateLedger(ledger){
    let schema=Joi.object({
    startDate:Joi.date().iso(),
    endDate:Joi.date().iso().greater(Joi.ref('startDate')),
    paymentFrequency:Joi.string().valid('weekly','fortnightly','monthly'),
    weeklyRate:Joi.number().greater(0),
    timeZone://this needs to be validated
    });

    return schema.validate(ledger)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just used joi-tz please find the code below

```
const Joi=require('joi')
const JoiTimezone=require('joi-tz')
const JoiTZ = Joi.extend(JoiTimezone);

function validateLedger(ledger){
    let schema=Joi.object({
    startDate:Joi.date().iso(),
    endDate:Joi.date().iso().greater(Joi.ref('startDate')),
    paymentFrequency:Joi.string().valid('weekly','fortnightly','monthly'),
    weeklyRate:Joi.number().greater(0),
    timeZone:JoiTZ.timezone().required()//the answer
    });

    return schema.validate(ledger)
}
```